# Fragments starting twice

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have this app in which im using fragments, but somehow everytime I start the app, every activity(fragment) is started two times. I'm banging my head about this but I cannot find an answer. Can someone help me?

Here is my main FragmentActivity:

```
public class TestSearch extends Activity {
    //this activity starts a fragment
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    // private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ArrayList<Device> devices;
    private ArrayList<Recepie> recepies, mainRecepies;
    private ArrayList<Recepie> searchResult;
    private LinearLayout sideWrapper;
    private EditText src;

    ArrayList<Categories> cats;

    boolean isTablet = false;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_search);
        Log.v("--", "started");
        if (Constants.isTablet(this)) {
            isTablet = true;
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        devices = new ArrayList<Device>();
        recepies = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
        mainRecepies = new ArrayList<Recepie>();

        devices = (ArrayList<Device>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(
                Constants.DEVICES_EXTRA);

        recepies = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("all");
        mainRecepies = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(
                Constants.MAINRECEPIES);
        // mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        cats = new ArrayList<Categories>();
        cats = (ArrayList<Categories>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("cats");

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
        sideWrapper = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.listwraper);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
        // opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        // View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.search_item,
        // null);
        src = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_est);
        src.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    Log.v("--", "Start search");
                    if (src.getText().length() > 0) {
                        searchResult = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
                        final ProgressDialog progress = ProgressDialog.show(
                                TestSearch.this,
                                getString(R.string.please_wait),
                                getString(R.string.getting_search_results),
                                true);
                        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                            protected void onPreExecute() {
                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                                        src.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            };

                            @Override
                            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                                searchResult = getSearchResults(src.getText()
                                        .toString());
                                return null;
                            }

                            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                                // set screen to search fragment
                                Fragment fragment = new SideSearchFragment();
                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putString("cat-title", src.getText()
                                        .toString());
                                args.putSerializable("cats", cats);
                                args.putBoolean(Constants.SEARCH, true);
                                args.putParcelableArrayList(
                                        Constants.SEARCH_RESULTS, searchResult);
                                fragment.setArguments(args);
                                progress.dismiss();
                                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                                        .addToBackStack("search_results")
                                        .commit();

                                // setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
                                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(sideWrapper);

                                // clear search text and hide keyboard
                                src.setText("");

                            };
                        }.execute();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
        SideAdapter adapter = new SideAdapter(this, cats);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        initActionBar();
        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            showMainFragment();
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void showFavoritesFragment() {

        Fragment fragment = new FavoritesFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable("all", recepies);
        args.putBoolean("search", true);
        args.putSerializable("cats", cats);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("favorites").commit();
    }

    private void showMainFragment() {
        Fragment fragment = new MainFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelableArrayList("all", recepies);
        args.putSerializable("cats", cats);
        args.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.MAINRECEPIES, mainRecepies);
        args.putBoolean("search", true);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(sideWrapper))
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(sideWrapper);
            else
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(sideWrapper);
            return true;

        case R.id.main_action_fav:

            showFavoritesFragment();
            return true;
        case R.id.main_action_choose_cats:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CircleListActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.DEVICES_EXTRA, devices);
            intent.putExtra("cats", cats);
            startActivity(intent);
            // finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void initActionBar() {
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#e91a34")));
        getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        // actionBar.setcu
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = new SearchFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("cat-title", cats.get(position).getTitle());
        args.putInt(Constants.CATEGORY_ID, cats.get(position).getId());
        args.putSerializable("cats", cats);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        // setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(sideWrapper);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        // mTitle = title;
        // getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        // mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        // mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    // This function gets the search results

    public ArrayList<Recepie> getSearchResults(String keyword) {
        ArrayList<Recepie> resultRecepie = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // get JSON data from URL
        JSONObject jObj = jParser
                .getJSONObjectFromUrl("http://oursson-recipes.outsourcingfarm.com/index.php/jsoner/getRecipe?query="
                        + keyword);

        try {
            JSONArray withTechnics = jObj.getJSONArray("with_technics");
            JSONArray withoutTechnics = jObj.getJSONArray("without_technics");
            for (int i = 0; i < withTechnics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject with = withTechnics.getJSONObject(i);
                boolean bool_tehcnics = true;
                if (with.getInt("with_technics") == 1)
                    bool_tehcnics = false;
                boolean my_devices = false;
                if (with.getInt("mydevices") == 1)
                    my_devices = true;
                JSONArray devices = with.getJSONArray("devices");
                ArrayList<Integer> devicesIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int k = 0; k < devices.length(); k++) {
                    devicesIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(devices.getString(k)));
                }

                resultRecepie.add(new Recepie(bool_tehcnics, my_devices, with
                        .getInt("id"), with.getInt("persons"), with
                        .getString("title"),
                        with.getString("preparation_time"), with
                                .getString("image_1"), devicesIDs));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < withoutTechnics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject with = withoutTechnics.getJSONObject(i);
                boolean bool_tehcnics = false;
                if (with.getInt("with_technics") == 1)
                    bool_tehcnics = true;
                boolean my_devices = false;
                if (with.getInt("mydevices") == 1)
                    my_devices = true;
                JSONArray devices = with.getJSONArray("devices");
                ArrayList<Integer> devicesIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int k = 0; k < devices.length(); k++) {
                    devicesIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(devices.getString(k)));
                }

                resultRecepie.add(new Recepie(bool_tehcnics, my_devices, with
                        .getInt("id"), with.getInt("persons"), with
                        .getString("title"),
                        with.getString("preparation_time"), with
                                .getString("image_1"), devicesIDs));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultRecepie;
    }

}
```

And here is a fragment(this one I start at the begining):

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private MainPhoneAdapter adapter;
    private boolean search = false;
    private ArrayList<Categories> cats;
    private ArrayList<Recepie> recepies, mainRecepies;
    private ArrayList<Recepie> withoTechnics;
    private ArrayList<Recepie> wTechnics;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    ImageView intro;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    Animation animationFadeOut;

    Display display;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        Log.v("--", "main create");
        if (Constants.isTablet(getActivity())) {
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else {
            getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                    ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        }

        cats = (ArrayList<Categories>) getArguments().getSerializable("cats");
        search = getArguments().getBoolean("search");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(
                getActivity().getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        initActionBar();
        mainRecepies = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
        recepies = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
        wTechnics = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
        withoTechnics = new ArrayList<Recepie>();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        if (getActivity().getIntent().getBooleanExtra("fromDevs", false)
                && search) {
            dialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            dialog.show();
            parseJson(rootView);
        } else {
            recepies = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("all");
            mainRecepies = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(
                    Constants.MAINRECEPIES);
            Log.v("--", mainRecepies.size() + " MAiN SIZE");
            // Log.v("--", "main frag" + recepies.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < mainRecepies.size(); i++) {
                if (mainRecepies.get(i).isWithTechnics())
                    wTechnics.add(mainRecepies.get(i));
                else
                    withoTechnics.add(mainRecepies.get(i));
            }
            if (Constants.isTablet(getActivity())) {
                populateViewForTablet(rootView);
                populateWithouTechnicsTablet(rootView);
                showAnimation(rootView);
            } else
                populateForPhones(rootView);
        }
        initImgLoader();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initActionBar() {
        getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#e91a34")));
        getActivity().getActionBar().setCustomView(
                R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        // actionBar.setcu
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setNavigationMode(
                ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        // getActivity().getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        // getActivity().getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.menu);
    }

    private void initImgLoader() {
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(
                ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getActivity()));
    }

    private void showAnimation(View view) {
        if (!prefs.getBoolean("main_shown", false)) {
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("main_shown", true).commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Overlay.class));
            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein,
                    R.anim.fadeout);
        }
    }

    private void parseJson(final View rootView) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // add static ids from prefs as device ID's
                String devs[] = prefs.getString(Constants.SELECTED_DEVICES,
                        "1,23,4").split(",");
                int end = devs.length;

                HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

                for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                    set.add(Integer.valueOf(devs[i]));
                }
                String devicesUrl = "";
                Iterator<Integer> it = set.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    devicesUrl += it.next() + ",";
                }
                devicesUrl = devicesUrl.substring(0, devicesUrl.length() - 1);
                Log.v("--", devicesUrl + " DV");

                getJSONFromUrl("http://oursson-recipes.outsourcingfarm.com/index.php/jsoner/getRecipe?devices="
                        + devicesUrl);
                getMainScreenRecepies("http://oursson-recipes.outsourcingfarm.com/index.php/jsoner/getHome?devices="
                        + devicesUrl);
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                // if TABLET
                if (Constants.isTablet(getActivity())) {
                    populateViewForTablet(rootView);
                    populateWithouTechnicsTablet(rootView);
                    showAnimation(rootView);
                } else
                    populateForPhones(rootView);

            };
        }.execute();
    }

    private void populateForPhones(View rootView) {
        ListView gridView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_grid);
        adapter = new MainPhoneAdapter(getActivity(), wTechnics);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        FullScreenBanner.class);
                intent.putExtra("cats", cats);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEPIES_EXTRA,
                        wTechnics.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("fromMain", true);
                intent.putExtra("recepieExtra", wTechnics.get(position).getId());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void populateViewForTablet(View rootView) {

        withTest(rootView);
    }

    //
    private void withTest(View rootView) {

        LinearLayout parent = ((LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.main_parent));

        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = (getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 3) * 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            final int position = i;
            View r = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.main_item_gray, parent, false);
            TextView top = (TextView) r
                    .findViewById(R.id.main_item_oursson_or_not);
            top.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redtint);
            ImageView itemBg = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_img);
            TextView title = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_title);
            TextView time = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_time);
            TextView persons = (TextView) r
                    .findViewById(R.id.main_item_persons);
            String imgLink = wTechnics.get(i).getImage_1()
                    .replace("[HEIGHT]", height + "")
                    .replace("[WIDTH]", width / 3 + "");

            title.setText(wTechnics.get(i).getTitle());
            time.setText(wTechnics.get(i).getPreparation_time());
            persons.setText(wTechnics.get(i).getPersons() + "");
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgLink, itemBg);
            parent.addView(r);
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            r.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            FullScreenBanner.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEPIES_EXTRA,
                            wTechnics.get(position));
                    intent.putExtra("cats", cats);
                    intent.putExtra("recepieExtra", wTechnics.get(position)
                            .getId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    //

    private void populateWithouTechnicsTablet(View rootView) {

        LinearLayout parent = ((LinearLayout) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.main_without));
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int height = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            final int position = i;
            View r = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
                    R.layout.main_item_gray_notfeatured, parent, false);
            ImageView itemBg = (ImageView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_img);
            TextView title = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_title);
            TextView time = (TextView) r.findViewById(R.id.main_item_time);
            TextView persons = (TextView) r
                    .findViewById(R.id.main_item_persons);

            String imgLink = withoTechnics.get(i).getImage_1()
                    .replace("[HEIGHT]", height + "")
                    .replace("[WIDTH]", width / 4 + "");

            title.setText(withoTechnics.get(i).getTitle());
            time.setText(withoTechnics.get(i).getPreparation_time());
            persons.setText(withoTechnics.get(i).getPersons() + "");
            ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgLink, itemBg);
            parent.addView(r);
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            r.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            FullScreenBanner.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Constants.RECEPIES_EXTRA,
                            withoTechnics.get(position));
                    intent.putExtra("cats", cats);
                    intent.putExtra("recepieExtra", withoTechnics.get(position)
                            .getId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void getMainScreenRecepies(String url) {
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // get JSON data from URL
        JSONObject jObj = jParser.getJSONObjectFromUrl(url);

        try {
            JSONArray withTechnics = jObj.getJSONArray("with_technics");
            JSONArray withoutTechnics = jObj.getJSONArray("without_technics");
            for (int i = 0; i < withTechnics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject with = withTechnics.getJSONObject(i);

                mainRecepies.add(new Recepie(true, with.getInt("id"), with
                        .getInt("persons"), with.getString("title"), with
                        .getString("preparation_time"), with
                        .getString("image_1")));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < withoutTechnics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject with = withoutTechnics.getJSONObject(i);

                mainRecepies.add(new Recepie(false, with.getInt("id"), with
                        .getInt("persons"), with.getString("title"), with
                        .getString("preparation_time"), with
                        .getString("image_1")));
            }
            Log.v("--", "PARSED " + mainRecepies.size() + "    " + url);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // get JSON data from URL
        JSONObject jObj = jParser.getJSONObjectFromUrl(url);
        Log.v("--", "asds");
        try {
            JSONArray withTechnics = jObj.getJSONArray("with_technics");
            JSONArray withoutTechnics = jObj.getJSONArray("without_technics");
            for (int i = 0; i < withTechnics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject with = withTechnics.getJSONObject(i);
                boolean bool_tehcnics = false;
                if (with.getInt("with_technics") == 1)
                    bool_tehcnics = true;
                boolean my_devices = false;
                if (with.getInt("mydevices") == 1)
                    my_devices = true;
                JSONArray devices = with.getJSONArray("devices");
                ArrayList<Integer> devicesIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int k = 0; k < devices.length(); k++) {
                    devicesIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(devices.getString(k)));
                }
                wTechnics.add(new Recepie(bool_tehcnics, my_devices, with
                        .getInt("id"), with.getInt("persons"), with
                        .getString("title"),
                        with.getString("preparation_time"), with
                                .getString("image_1"), devicesIDs));

                recepies.add(new Recepie(bool_tehcnics, my_devices, with
                        .getInt("id"), with.getInt("persons"), with
                        .getString("title"),
                        with.getString("preparation_time"), with
                                .getString("image_1"), devicesIDs));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < withoutTechnics.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject with = withoutTechnics.getJSONObject(i);
                boolean bool_tehcnics = false;
                if (with.getInt("with_technics") == 1)
                    bool_tehcnics = true;
                boolean my_devices = false;
                if (with.getInt("mydevices") == 1)
                    my_devices = true;
                JSONArray devices = with.getJSONArray("devices");
                ArrayList<Integer> devicesIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int k = 0; k < devices.length(); k++) {
                    devicesIDs.add(Integer.valueOf(devices.getString(k)));
                }
                withoTechnics.add(new Recepie(bool_tehcnics, my_devices, with
                        .getInt("id"), with.getInt("persons"), with
                        .getString("title"),
                        with.getString("preparation_time"), with
                                .getString("image_1"), devicesIDs));

                recepies.add(new Recepie(bool_tehcnics, my_devices, with
                        .getInt("id"), with.getInt("persons"), with
                        .getString("title"),
                        with.getString("preparation_time"), with
                                .getString("image_1"), devicesIDs));
            }
            Log.v("--", recepies.size() + " RS");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you see that?

Comment: @Luksprog When I test the app on a tablet and also in logCat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fragment called twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556032/fragment-called-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a newInstance method will correct this starting of two fragments.  Ad populum I see alot of newInstance code when I'm looking at fragment examples.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

public static Fragment newInstance(int instance# pass in receipieces and cats here) {
    MainFragment f = new MainFragment();
    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelableArrayList("all", recepies);
    args.putSerializable("cats", cats);
    args.putParcelableArrayList(Constants.MAINRECEPIES, mainRecepies);
    args.putBoolean("search", true);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}
```

meanwhile back in the activity that shows the fragment use new instance to start the fragment.

```
private void showMainFragment() {
    Fragment fragment = MainFragment.newInstacne(instance# pass in recipies and cats here);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
            .commit();

}
```